# How can I use shareReplay in combineLatest?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have components that use `combineLatest` heavily. For example, in one component I have:

```js
const users$ = this.http.get<User[]>('URL');
const userAction$ = this.http.get<User>('Another Url');

combineLatest(
    this.userAction$,
    this.users$
)
.pipe(
    map(([users, action]) => {
        this.display(users, action);
    })
);
```

The `users$ = this.http.get<User[]>('URL');` is used in every component. So the HTTP requests are duplicated in every component.

For example, in another component I have similar code.

```js
const users$ = this.http.get<User[]>('URL');
const flag$ = this.http.get<Flag>('Flag Url');

combineLatest(
    this.flag$,
    this.users$
)
.pipe(
    map(([users, flag]) => {
        this.setMap(users);
        this.extractFlag(flag); 
    })
);
```

We also use the same `users$ = this.http.get<User[]>('URL');` here.

I've tried using `shareReplay` like this:

```js
users$ = this.http.get<User[]>('URL').pipe(shareReplay(1));
```

However it doesn't seem to work; I still can see multiple HTTP requests.

**Update:**

The above code is just a demo. Actually I use service to do that.

```
const flag$ = this.http.get<Flag>('Flag Url');

combineLatest(
    this.flag$,
    this.apiService.users$
)
.pipe(
    map(([users, flag]) => {
        this.setMap(users);
        this.extractFlag(flag); 
    })
);
```

I api.service, I have

```
public users$ = (): Observable<User[]> => {
   return this.http.get<User[]>('URL').pipe(shareReplay(1));
}
```

Comment: Are you duplicating that line of code? `users$ =  ...` or is there a service supplying the same (now shared) observable to each component. If it's the first, there's no magic in the observable library that understands the internals of what you're doing.

Comment: It is from a service, I append `shareReplay(1)` in the method of the service. Just no lucky.

Comment: To the method? Are you create a static value or generating a new observable per method call?

Comment: Please see my update.

Comment: You’re returning a new observable every time.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```ts
public users$ = (): Observable<User[]> => {
   return this.http.get<User[]>('URL').pipe(shareReplay(1));
}
```

to

```ts
private _users$ = this.http.get<User[]>('URL').pipe(shareReplay(1));
public users$ = (): Observable<User[]> => _users$;
```

The `public users$` function is redundant, but we'll keep it here so you don't have the change the public API of your service when testing this. I think this should work :)

Comment: It is closed to the answer. But if you create a private field. The question is that I can't get the `URL`. I passed it in the constructor rather than hard code it. The error is `URL is used before its intialization`.